# Why is "this" needed before a C# extension method, if I'm inside one of the extended class' subclass?

Tags: c#

I've defined an **extension method** for my **FadeableGroup** class in MyUtility.cs.

```
public static class MyUtility
{
    public static void StartFadingIn(this FadeableGroup fadeableGroup, float duration)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then I tried using the extension method **inside a subclass of FadeableGroup** in MyClass.cs.

But unless I explicitly write **"this"**, the compiler **can't recognise the extension method**.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass : FadeableGroup
    {
        private void Test()
        {
            this.StartFadingIn(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it need a **this**? Thanks! :)

Comment: The extension methods need to know what reference to work against. It’s not a magic scope modification

Comment: If you left out `this` it would look for `void StartFadingIn(float duration)` which is a different method.

Comment: But then my next question is: if I define a StartFadingIn(...) in the class, why doesn't the compiler warn me that there is already one defined on the class? I guess the result would be just silently overriding the extension method, right? Or what happens exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because that's how the spec says you should call them.**

> [**12.8.9.3 Extension method invocations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12893-extension-method-invocations)
>
> In a method invocation ([§12.6.6.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12662-invocations-on-boxed-instances)) of one of the forms
> C#
>
> ```
> «expr» . «identifier» ( )  
> «expr» . «identifier» ( «args» )  
> «expr» . «identifier» < «typeargs» > ( )  
> «expr» . «identifier» < «typeargs» > ( «args» )
> ```
>
> if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation.

In other words, an attempt to match an extension method is only made if, and only if, the syntax `expr.Method` is used. You cannot just use `Method` and expect an extension to be used automatically.

While the language designers probably *could* have made this possible, I expect they thought (rightly probably) that it would be too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because C# needs a reference to the instance or type you are calling via an extension method. The `this` helps the compiler resolve the type so it knows where to look to find the extension method.

Also, extension methods do not override instance methods so if you declare a `StartFadingIn` method with a matching signature in `FadeableGroup` then the extension method never gets called.

Comment: I doubt there is any *technical* reason it couldn't work to automatically search for an extension method on `this`, it's just not in the spec. The fact extension methods don't override instance methods seems irrelevant, the same is true of any extension invocation.